# Select dates from Multiple columns in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I am looking for a bit of help creating an HTML table that will list the next 5 upcoming dates stored within a Mysql table.
I have a table which has 2 String columns & 10 different date columns:

What I want to do is create a HTML table with the following headers:
**Mare,
Treatment &
Date**

The **Date** column will be filled with the 5 dates.

The **Treatment** column will be filled with the MySql column name of that date

The **Mare** column will be filled with the mare string of that dates row

I am trying to write an SQL statement that will take every date from each of the columns, check to see if is greater than today's date, order by date and limit to 5.

What I have so far is as follows:

```
SELECT covering, 
 ovulation, 
 pregnancy, 
 scanfortwins, 
 heartbeatscan, 
 antiabortion1, 
 antiabortion2, 
 antiabortion3, 
 removestitches, 
 duedate 
 FROM   `dates` 
 WHERE  'covering' 
  AND 'ovulation' 
  AND 'pregnancy' 
  AND 'scanfortwins' 
  AND 'heartbeatscan' 
  AND 'antiabortion1' 
  AND 'antiabortion2' 
  AND 'antiabortion3' 
  AND 'removestitches' 
  AND 'duedate' >= Curdate() 
  ORDER  BY Year(date) DESC, 
  Month(date) DESC, 
  Day(date) DESC 
  LIMIT  5;
```

If I could get a bit of help creating the HTML table it would be much appreciated

Comment: I had a look into Normalization, but am unsure as to what to do

Comment: Well, in a normalized design there would only be one column for (treatment) dates.

Comment: right, so I would have to redesign me table structure?

Comment: Yes. Normalization (to a state known as 3NF) is a prerequisite of relational databases. Otherwise, you may as well just store the data in a plain text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting from a UNION sub-query, as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT ovulation AS `Date`, 'ovulation' AS Treatment, Mare
   FROM `dates`
   WHERE ovulation > DATE()
   ORDER BY ovulation ASC
   LIMIT 5
   UNION
   SELECT pregnancy AS `Date`, 'pregnancy' AS Treatment, Mare
   FROM `date`
   WHERE pregnancy > DATE()
   ORDER BY pregnancy ASC
   LIMIT 5
   ...
) AS x
ORDER BY x.`Date` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thanks a million, with a small bit of tweaking this worked! Just had to place each select statement inside individual opening and closing brackets, thank you for your help :)